# Vuex getter data disappears on refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using a "getter" to get data for an overlay component from my Vuex store. When the user clicks on a router link, I pass the ID of the quote in the parameters into the child component and the getter uses the ID to fetch the particular quote from the store.

Everything works nicely until when I refresh the page the data fetched using the disappears.

Component with router link:

```
<v-row>
    <v-col v-for="(quote, $index) in quotes" :key="$index" cols="3">
        <v-card @click="openQuoteEditor(quote)">
            <v-card-title>{{ quote.projectName }}</v-card-title>
        </v-card>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

openQuoteEditor method:

```
methods: {
    openQuoteEditor(quote) {
        this.$router.push({
            name: "QuoteEditor",
            params: { id: quote.uid }
        })
    }
}
```

router.js:

```
   {
        path: "/all-quotes",
        name: "AllQuotes",
        component: () => import("../views/AllQuotes.vue"),
        children: [
            {
                path: "quote/:id",
                name: "QuoteEditor",
                component: () => import("../components/QuoteEditor.vue")
            }
        ]
    }
```

Vuex store.js:

```
getters: {
    getQuote(state) {
        return id => {
            for (const quote of state.quotesCollection.quotesCollection) {
                if (quote.uid == id) {
                    return quote
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

component JS:

```
import { mapGetters } from "vuex"

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            name: "QuoteEditor"
        }
    },
    props: ["id"],
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(["getQuote"]),
        quote() {
            return this.getQuote(this.$route.params.id)
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be super! Thank you!

Comment: You either need to persist the data in session or local storage, or fetch the data again after refresh. VueX does not persist data for you automagically.

Comment: Thanks @Terry! do you have a link on how to fetch data after refresh for vuex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vuex doesn't persist the data by default.
You may use this package https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate
which persists data by storing them in local storage.

However, if you are using it in ssr/universal mode, you need to do further tweak to make it work you may follow this issue threads.

Comment: Thanks Abdur - vuex-persistedstate worked for me but I realised that i must first make a commit before the plugin can save the current state in local storage in case anyone else run into an issue of the plugin not working for you when first installed.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but after setting up the package all you need to do is regular vuex usage.